# Autobinomonorownonomicrogram

Tags: nonogram

<sub>(Bonus / bounty follow-up challenges have been moved to
 [*Semiïnfinite autobinomonorownonomicrogram*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48760/semi%c3%afnfinite-autobinomonorownonomicrogram))</sub>

> ☆   **Be the**  <del>first</del> 
>                               **next to make your own
>                                 nontrivial autobinomonorownonomicrogram**
>                 ☆

“Impossible!” you scoff?
 
Might indeed be, except that your autobinomonorownonomicrogram
may be **infinitely wide**
and include **leading 0**s, as in 01 or 0010.
$
\require{begingroup}\begingroup
 \def \l  { \kern-.3em\cdots~ } \def \L  { & ~\cdots\kern -.1em                }
  \def \r {           ~\cdots }  \def \R {           \kern-.2em\cdots~\\\hline }
   \def \p     {  \phantom{ \Rule {2.5ex}{2.0ex}{0.5ex}} }
    \def \X    {\kern-.5em   \Rule{2.5ex}{2.0ex}{0.5ex}             \kern-.5em}
     \def \b   {\kern-.5em                                     \p   \kern-.5em}
      \def \1  {\kern-.5em\rlap {\normalsize \bf \kern .2em 1 } \p  \kern-.5em}
       \def \0 {\kern-.5em \rlap{ \scriptsize     \kern.3em 0 }  \p \kern-.5em}
$

“*Nontrivial*  ?” you might ask.
 
Well, *trivial* autobinomonorownonomicrograms are just too common.

$\small\begin{array}{c|c|} \sf\scriptsize Consecutive~counts~(in~binary)
                            \L   & 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& \R
                             \l    0  1~~0  1~~0  1~~1  0~~1~~0  1~~0  1   \r
                              \L &\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&   \R
\end{array}$

is a trivial one that solves to

 
$\small\begin{array}{c|c|}  \L   & 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& \R
                             \l    0  1~~0  1~~0  1~~1  0~~1~~0  1~~0  1   \r
                              \L &\0&\1&\0&\1&\0&\1&\1&\0&\1&\0&\1&\0&\1&   \R
\end{array}$

Note how the same infinite digit sequence
... 0 1 0 1 0 11 0 1 0 1 0 1...
constitutes both the margins’ counts
and the interior’s cells.
(These counts are
 [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Counting_in_binary),
 so 10 = 2.)
 
This example is called *trivial* as...

> ...**nontrivial** here means
>   that multiple pairs of adjacent **1**s
>   occur among the cells.
>   The example does not qualify because
>   it has only one adjacent pair of 1s.
>
> “**Autobinomonorownonomicrogram**?”
>    
>   It’s short for auto-bino-monorow-nono[micro]gram.
>   
>   
>           auto:   Self-descriptive — cells’
>                                                contents match the margin
>                                                counts’ actual digits.
>   
>           bino:   [Binary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Counting_in_binary).
>   
>                monorow:   Exactly one row tall.
>   
>                      nonogram:   [This type of grid puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram).
>   
>        micro:   No numbers greater
>                                                than 2, which shows as binary
>                                                **10** (or 010, 0010, ...).
>   
>         
>   (Thus 3 consecutive cells cannot be all **1**s.)

**Evolutionary path of autobinomonorownonomicrograms.**
Begin with a familiar
[nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram)
such as this 3×8,
where numbers at its left and top margins are
length counts of consecutive filled cells
in their respective rows and columns.

$$\small\begin{array}{r|c|}
                   &    &    &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &               \\[-1ex]
                   &  0 &  2 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  2 \kern.05em \\
\hline      2 ~~ 3 & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b \kern.05em \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~ 1 & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b \kern.05em \\
\hline      3 ~~ 2 & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b \kern.05em \\
\hline \end   {array}
 \qquad \begin{array}{r|c|}
                   &    &    &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &               \\[-1ex]
                   &  0 &  2 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  2 \kern.05em \\
\hline      2 ~~ 3 & \b & \b & \X & \X & \b & \X & \X & \X \kern.05em \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~ 1 & \b & \X & \b & \b & \X & \b & \b & \X \kern.05em \\
\hline      3 ~~ 2 & \b & \X & \X & \X & \b & \X & \X & \b \kern.05em \\
\hline \end{array}$$

Turn that into **binary**,
where **0**s and **1**s indicate empty and full cells
while binary numbers are used for counts.
This already happens to be **nontrivial** as it has multiple
sets of adjacent **1** cells.

$$\small\begin{array}{r|c|}
                    &    &          &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &       \\[-1ex]
                    &  0 & \! 10 \! &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 & \! 10 \\
\hline     10 ~~ 11 & \b &    \b    & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &    \b \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~  1 & \b &    \b    & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &    \b \\
\hline     11 ~~ 10 & \b &    \b    & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &    \b \\
\hline \end   {array}
 \qquad \begin{array}{r|c|}
                    &    &          &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &       \\[-1ex]
                    &  0 & \! 10 \! &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 & \! 10 \\
\hline     10 ~~ 11 & \0 &    \0    & \1 & \1 & \0 & \1 & \1 &    \1 \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~  1 & \0 &    \1    & \0 & \0 & \1 & \0 & \0 &    \1 \\
\hline     11 ~~ 10 & \0 &    \1    & \1 & \1 & \0 & \1 & \1 &    \0 \\
\hline \end{array}$$

Empty a couple of corner-cell 1s to attain the **micro** quality,
having counts only of **0**, **1** and **10**.

$$\small\begin{array}{r|c|}
                    &    &      &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &      \\[-1ex]
                    &  0 &\bf 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &\bf 1 \\
\hline   10~~\bf 10 & \b &   \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &   \b \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~  1 & \b &   \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &   \b \\
\hline{\bf 10}~~ 10 & \b &   \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &   \b \\
\hline \end   {array}
 \qquad \begin{array}{r|c|}
                    &    &      &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &      \\[-1ex]
                    &  0 &\bf 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &\bf 1 \\
\hline   10~~\bf 10 & \0 &   \0 & \1 & \1 & \0 & \1 & \1 &   \0 \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~  1 & \0 &   \1 & \0 & \0 & \1 & \0 & \0 &   \1 \\
\hline{\bf 10}~~ 10 & \0 &   \0 & \1 & \1 & \0 & \1 & \1 &   \0 \\
\hline \end{array}$$

Almost there, pare down to just **one row**.
The following 1×$\kern1mu\raise1mu\infty$ nonogram
*would* be an autobinomonorownonomicrogram
if only its digits were exactly matched.
But its cells contain a 1 (circled)
where the counts’ digits do not ($\,\scriptsize\wedge\,$).

$$\small\begin{array}{r|c|} \L    & 0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& \R
                             \l    ~0  1~~1  0~~1
  \rlap{\kern-.25em\scriptsize\raise-1.5ex\wedge}    0~~1~~0  1   \r
                               \L &\0&\1&\1&\0&\1&\1
  \rlap{\kern-.65em\Large\raise-.1ex\bigcirc}      &\0&\1&\0&\1&  \R
\end{array}$$

This nonetheless qualifies as *nontrivial*
because two pairs of adjacent cells contain 1s.

$\endgroup$

Comment: Can the solution to this just be a pronunciation of .. that word in the title?

Comment: Gotta admit, the word makes it easy to get
15 letters into a puzzle title.
Anyone happen to have an etymologically more apt replacement for "auto"
in _autobinomonorownonomicrogram_?
Or for some other part of the word?
Without making the result seem any more serious than it already does,
of course.

Comment: It's 9°F here today. My car made this *exact* noise when I first went to start it. True story.

Comment: Man I got tired just trying to pronounce that title. Which part of it was trivial, again?

Comment: @Xenocacia: None of them!

Comment: -1; unpronounceable title.

Comment: I want this to reach HNQs just so that as many people as possible see that title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This satisfies the requirements:

> [image]

I've provided a decimal conversion row and highlighted the locations of `11`s in the "clue".

Comment: Looking good, Deusovi, good and quick!
Thought I'd get to wait longer before adding
a certain bonus/bounty challenge. You'll see.
(This is also a feeler for a more complex
nonogram puzzle in the works.)

Comment: @humn: I see lots of ways this can be extended! Is it something to do with one of the 2s corresponding to itself in both interpretations, or maybe making it only extend infinitely in one direction?

Comment: Deusovi, did you know that your solution can be modified
to extend in just one direction?
It can, and [was](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47619/18129),
duly credited.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(Extension of an answer to the original bonus question’s
 [semi-infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-infinite)
 challenge.)</sup>

Here’s a “mid-infinite”
nontrivial autobinomonorownonomicrogram,
with neatly finite left and right margins
in the spirit of an infinite
[dragon curve’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve)
fixed endpoints.

> [image]
>  
>  <sub>(Derived from
>  [Deusovi’s solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47526/18129).)</sub>

Lingering question:
 
Can a mid-infinite solution have infinitely many pairs of adjacent **1**s
(and thus infinitely many counts of **10**).
Only two pairs of adjacent cells here are **1**s.