# Semiïnfinite autobinomonorownonomicrogram

Tags: nonogram

<sub>(Scroll down for a bonus / bounty follow-up question)</sub>

> **You too can be the very first
>                                 to make your very own**
>   
>        
>               ☆   **semiïnfinitely significant
>                                 autobinomonorownonomicrogram**
>                 ☆

“But I already have my very own
       [**mid**-infinite autobinomonorownonomicrogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47619),”
you pule?
 
Of course you have —yawn — by now,
who doesn’t?

As contrast, here is a run-of-the-mill
**bi**ïnfinite (bi-infinite) autobinomonorownonomicrogram.
$
\require{begingroup}\begingroup
 \def \l  { \kern-.3em\cdots~ } \def \L  { & ~\cdots\kern -.1em                }
  \def \r {           ~\cdots }  \def \R {           \kern-.2em\cdots~\\\hline }
   \def \p     {  \phantom{ \Rule {2.5ex}{2.0ex}{0.5ex}} }
\def \X    {\kern-.5em   \Rule{2.5ex}{2.0ex}{0.5ex}             \kern-.5em}
 \def \b   {\kern-.5em                                     \p   \kern-.5em}
  \def \1  {\kern-.5em\rlap {\normalsize \bf \kern .2em 1 } \p  \kern-.5em}
   \def \0 {\kern-.5em \rlap{ \scriptsize     \kern.3em 0 }  \p \kern-.5em}
$

$\small\begin{array}{c|c|} \sf\scriptsize Consecutive~counts~(in~binary)
                        \L   & 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& \R
                         \l    0  1~~0  1~~0  1~~1  0~~1~~0  1~~0  1   \r
                          \L &\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b&   \R
\end{array}$

And its solution.

 
$\small\begin{array}{c|c|}  \L   & 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& \R
                         \l    0  1~~0  1~~0  1~~1  0~~1~~0  1~~0  1   \r
                          \L &\0&\1&\0&\1&\0&\1&\1&\0&\1&\0&\1&\0&\1&   \R
\end{array}$

Note how the same infinite digit sequence
... 0 1 0 1 0 11 0 1 0 1 0 1...
constitutes both the margins’ counts
and the interior’s cells.
(These counts are
 [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Counting_in_binary),
 so 10 = 2.)
 
The present puzzle, however, seeks:

> A **semiïnfinite** (semi-infinite) grid,
>   which extends infinitely only leftward or rightward but not both.
>    
>   (The example above is *bi*ïnfinite as it extends in both directions.)
>
> A **significant** grid,
>   meaning that it contains infinitely many row counts of **10**
>   and thus infinitely many **1 1** adjacencies among cells.
>    
>   (The example has only one row count of **10** and
>    only one corresponding **1 1** cell adjacency.)

Here is a schematic of a *right*-extended
semiïnfinitely significant autobinomonorownonomicrogram.

$$\small \def \s #1#2{{\scriptsize\raise1.3ex\matrix{ \sf #1 \\[-1ex] \sf #2 }}}
\begin{array}{c|c|} &\s {some}{counts} & 1& 1&\cdots  & 1& 1&\cdots  & 1& 1&\R
                  \s{some}{counts} ~ 10 ~  \cdots ~ 10 ~  \cdots ~ 10    \r
                &  \s{some}{cells} &\1&\1&  \cdots&\1&\1&  \cdots&\1&\1&  \R
\end{array}$$

> “**Autobinomonorownonomicrogram**?”
>    
>   It’s short for auto-bino-monorow-nono[micro]gram.
>   
>   
>           auto:   Self-descriptive — cells’
>                                                contents match the margin
>                                                counts’ actual digits.
>   
>           bino:   [Binary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Counting_in_binary).
>   
>                monorow:   Exactly one row tall.
>   
>                      nonogram:   [This type of grid puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram).
>   
>        micro:   No numbers greater
>                                                than 2, which shows as binary
>                                                **10** (or 010, 0010, ...).
>   
>         
>   (Thus 3 consecutive cells cannot be all **1**s.)

**Evolutionary path of autobinomonorownonomicrograms.**
Begin with a familiar
[nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram)
such as this 3×8,
where numbers at its left and top margins are
length counts of consecutive filled cells
in their respective rows and columns.

$$\small\begin{array}{r|c|}
               &    &    &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &               \\[-1ex]
               &  0 &  2 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  2 \kern.05em \\
\hline      2 ~~ 3 & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b \kern.05em \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~ 1 & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b \kern.05em \\
\hline      3 ~~ 2 & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b \kern.05em \\
\hline \end   {array}
 \qquad \begin{array}{r|c|}
               &    &    &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &               \\[-1ex]
               &  0 &  2 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  2 \kern.05em \\
\hline      2 ~~ 3 & \b & \b & \X & \X & \b & \X & \X & \X \kern.05em \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~ 1 & \b & \X & \b & \b & \X & \b & \b & \X \kern.05em \\
\hline      3 ~~ 2 & \b & \X & \X & \X & \b & \X & \X & \b \kern.05em \\
\hline \end{array}$$

Turn that into **binary**,
where **0**s and **1**s indicate empty and full cells
while binary numbers are used for counts.

$$\small\begin{array}{r|c|}
                &    &          &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &       \\[-1ex]
                &  0 & \! 10 \! &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 & \! 10 \\
\hline     10 ~~ 11 & \b &    \b    & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &    \b \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~  1 & \b &    \b    & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &    \b \\
\hline     11 ~~ 10 & \b &    \b    & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &    \b \\
\hline \end   {array}
 \qquad \begin{array}{r|c|}
                &    &          &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &       \\[-1ex]
                &  0 & \! 10 \! &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 & \! 10 \\
\hline     10 ~~ 11 & \0 &    \0    & \1 & \1 & \0 & \1 & \1 &    \1 \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~  1 & \0 &    \1    & \0 & \0 & \1 & \0 & \0 &    \1 \\
\hline     11 ~~ 10 & \0 &    \1    & \1 & \1 & \0 & \1 & \1 &    \0 \\
\hline \end{array}$$

Empty a couple of corner-cell 1s to attain the **micro** quality,
having counts only of **0**, **1** and **10**.

$$\small\begin{array}{r|c|}
                &    &      &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &      \\[-1ex]
                &  0 &\bf 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &\bf 1 \\
\hline   10~~\bf 10 & \b &   \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &   \b \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~  1 & \b &   \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &   \b \\
\hline{\bf 10}~~ 10 & \b &   \b & \b & \b & \b & \b & \b &   \b \\
\hline \end   {array}
 \qquad \begin{array}{r|c|}
                &    &      &  1 &  1 &    &  1 &  1 &      \\[-1ex]
                &  0 &\bf 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &\bf 1 \\
\hline   10~~\bf 10 & \0 &   \0 & \1 & \1 & \0 & \1 & \1 &   \0 \\
\hline 1 ~~ 1 ~~  1 & \0 &   \1 & \0 & \0 & \1 & \0 & \0 &   \1 \\
\hline{\bf 10}~~ 10 & \0 &   \0 & \1 & \1 & \0 & \1 & \1 &   \0 \\
\hline \end{array}$$

Almost there, pare down to just **one row**.
The following 1×$\kern1mu\raise1mu\infty$ nonogram
*would* be an autobinomonorownonomicrogram
if only its digits were exactly matched.
But its cells contain a 1 (circled)
where the counts’ digits do not ($\,\scriptsize\wedge\,$).

$$\small\begin{array}{r|c|} \L    & 0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& \R
                         \l    ~0  1~~1  0~~1
  \rlap{\kern-.25em\scriptsize\raise-1.5ex\wedge}    0~~1~~0  1   \r
                           \L &\0&\1&\1&\0&\1&\1
  \rlap{\kern-.65em\Large\raise-.1ex\bigcirc}      &\0&\1&\0&\1&  \R
\end{array}$$

**Bonus** / **bounty question:**
 
Can a **bi**ïnfinite significant autobinomonorownonomicrogram
infinitely repeat an unchanging pattern?
 
(Doubtful at pose time,
 but also a hint for the present puzzle.)

$$\small \def \s #1#2{{\scriptsize\raise1.3ex\matrix{ \sf #1 \\[-1ex] \sf #2 }}}
\begin{array}{c|c|}\L   & 1& 1& \cdots & 1& 1& \cdots & 1& 1& \cdots & 1& 1&\R
                \l  10 ~ \s{some}{counts} ~ 10 ~ \s  {same}{counts} ~ 10 \r
                 \L &\1&\1&\s{some}{cells}&\1&\1& \s {same}{cells}&\1&\1&
                                                   \s{same}{cells}&\1&\1& \R
\end{array}$$

$\endgroup$

Comment: '“But I already have my very own mid-infinitely autobinomonorownonomicrogram,” you pule?' - what does pule mean?

Comment: Don't take it wrong, @boboquack, I'm not calling you a pule, that would be silly! Actually, that would be _puler_. (_Pule_ is a verb: to whimper, whine, cry weakly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one I can confirm is possible!

> Mine's left-infinite - `...110101010101101010101101010110101101` with ever-decreasing-length segments (from L to R) of `01010...10`s between the `11`s

This can be broken up like so:

> `...1 1 01 01 01 010 1 1 01 01 010 1 1 01 010 1 1 010 1 10 1` where the first `1 10 1` is not part of any pattern but before that we have `010`s with 2 `1`s and the correct number of `01`s to pad which is also decreasing (from L to R) at the correct rate.

Picture from @humn:

> [image]

Comment: I knew you'd be ready for this one, boboquack. Alternate bounty for another semiïnfinitely significant autobinomonorownonomicrogram that isn't a superset of this, or a could-be-less-than-rigorous proof of none such possible. (I'm already very curious to know how you got this particular semiïnfinitely significant autobinomonorownonomicrogram so quickly.)

Comment: @humn a bit of a case bash with some common-sense did it, was this your solution?

Comment: Yes, same, boboquack, reached with a fair amount of analysis after the previous puzzle got solved surprisingly quickly. I doubt anyone else would have solved this, with a cold start, even half as quickly as you, and am surprised again anyway. This is essentially a cellular-automaton situation in disguise.